# Find all $f$, $f\in C^{\infty}$, $\frac{df}{d\bar{z}} = z$

Tags: complex-analysis

So far I've got
$$
2\frac{df}{d\bar{z}} = \frac{du}{dx}-\frac{dv}{dy} + i (\frac{du}{dy}+\frac{dv}{dx}) = x + iy,
$$
from which I concluded
$$
\frac{du}{dx} - \frac{dv}{dy} = 2x
$$
and
$$
\frac{du}{dy} + \frac{dv}{dx} = 2y.
$$

I derivated these equations and eventually I got $\frac{d^2v}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2v}{dy^2} = 0$. Wolfram gave me result $v = c_1(y+ix) + c_2(y-ix)$ but the teacher insists there are more options for $v$ so I'm confused, is wolfram wrong? Missing constant shouldn't be a problem, I added it later. Or something else? (except me using wolfram :D but noone really taught us how to do partial differential eq.)

Comment: Any harmonic $v$ is a solution of your last equation, e.g. , $v$ can be any real or imaginary part of an entire function on $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Note that $c_1$ and $c_2$ here are functions, not constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = z$$
to use the standard notation. No big deal.

First, find a particular solution. Let's check that
$$f= z \cdot \bar z$$
is one. Indeed, we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} z\bar z= \frac{\partial z }{\partial \bar z} \bar z + z \frac{\partial \bar z }{\partial \bar z} = 0 \cdot \bar z + z \cdot 1 = z$$

Now, any other solution $f$ will be $ z \bar z + f_0$ where $f_0$ solution to the equation $\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \bar z} = 0$, that is $|z|^2 + $ an entire function.